# Импорт константы

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаюсь импортировать константу idUser (присваивается после нажатия кнопки):

```
app.post('/user', (req, res) => {
    const userData = req.body;
    idUser = userData.id;
    console.log(userData);
    conn.query(`INSERT INTO sessions(idSession, userId, dateStartSession) VALUES(${RandomValue()}, ${userData.id}, '${moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}')`, (err, results) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            module.exports.idUser = userData.id;
        }
    })
    res.send('Данные успешно получены на сервере');
});
```

После чего записываю ее в БД:

```
async function getIdUser() {
  idUsers = await idUser;
  conn.query(`INSERT INTO sessions(idSession, idUser) VALUES(${randomValue()}, ${idUser.id})`, (err, results) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  })
}
```

Но получаю undefined idUser. Понимаю, что это связано с асинхронностью, но не понимаю как решить

Comment: Не думаю, что вы можете такое сделать.

Comment: экспортировать надо либо функцию возвращающую Promise, либо сам Promise